# GraphQL + Java - How do I filter subfields?

Tags: java, annotations, graphql, graphql-java

I am using [graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java) with [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) in my Spring application ([spring-graphql-common](https://github.com/oembedler/spring-graphql-common/) seemed very limited and looks like it's not maintained anymore), and I'm struggling with subfields manipulation.

I have two classes `A` and `B` that I want to access using GraphQL, here they are:

```
class A {
    @GraphQLField
    Integer id;
    @GraphQLField
    String name;
    @GraphQLField
    List<B> listOfB;
}

class B {
    @GraphQLField
    Integer id;
    @GraphQLField
    String code;
}
```

I can successfully query all the fields in `A` and also the fields in `B` using the following schema:

```
@Component
public class Schema
{
    public GraphQLObjectType aType;
    public GraphQLSchema aSchema;
    public GraphQLObjectType queryType;

    @Autowired
    public Schema(DataFetcher dataFetcher) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        aType = GraphQLAnnotations.object(A.class);

        queryType =
                GraphQLObjectType
                .newObject()
                    .name("QueryType")
                    .field(GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition()
                        .name("a")
                        .type(aType)
                        .argument(GraphQLArgument.newArgument()
                                .name("id")
                                .type(new GraphQLNonNull(Scalars.GraphQLInt))
                                .build())
                        .dataFetcher(dataFetcher)
                        .build())
                    .build();

        aSchema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
                .query(queryType)
                .build();
    }
}
```

I can successfully filter on `a` with the following request:

```
{
    a(id:5)
    {
        id,
        name,
        listOfB
        {
            code
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to filter on `listOfB`, for example with a `take` to select only X records, I have the error `Validation error of type UnknownArgument: Unknown argument take`:

```
{
    a(id:5)
    {
        id,
        name,
        listOfB(take:3)
        {
            code
        }
    }
}
```

I understand what the error means, as I haven't declared any possible argument for the `listOfB` field on `A`, but I don't know how I could possibly do it using `graphql-java-annotations`.

I have added a specific `DataFetcher` for `listOfB` tho, using the following code in class `A`:

```
@GraphQLDataFetcher(BDataFetcher.class)
private List<B> listOfB;
```

and it is indeed getting called when I retrieve `listOfB`.

Do you have any idea on how I could add arguments to fields when using `graphql-java-annotations`? If not, is there any workaround?

Defining the schema without annotations and using the "classic" way of `graphql-java` is not an option as my schema is really huge :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried to add a @GraphQLField in listOfB field together with the @GraphQLDataFetcher? I'm doing some tests here and worked.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm sorry, it was still a `GraphQLField` with the DataFetcher. But I'm still getting the same error. I managed to make it work by defining `listOfB` as a method instead of a field, but it ended up being way to tedious so I'm currently writing custom annotations to allow filtering automatically on any field just by adding a `@GraphQLAnnotation` annotation on it.

Comment: I have similar problem like here, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790053/how-to-filtering-subfields-in-spring-boot-graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the solution I ended up using because it doesn't fit my design, but here's what you can do:

```
public class MyClass
{
    @GraphQLField
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> items;

    @GraphQLField
    public List<String> items(DataFetchingEnvironment environment, @GraphQLName("take") Integer take, @GraphQLName("after") Integer after)
    {
        List<String> items = ((MyClass) environment.getSource()).getItems();

        Integer fromIndex = 0;
        Integer toIndex = items.size();
        if (after != null)
            fromIndex = after + 1;
        if (take != null)
            toIndex = fromIndex + take;

        return items.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }
}
```

It sucks because you're not using a `DataFetcher` so your code will be copy/pasted everywhere, but it still works.

But I found a way to use a `DataFetcher`, that said it's weird and I guess it's not a proper use of the library, but who knows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    @GraphQLField
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> items;

    @GraphQLField
    @GraphQLDataFetcher(MyClassDataFetcher.class)
    public List<String> items(DataFetchingEnvironment environment, @GraphQLName("take") Integer take, @GraphQLName("after") Integer after)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This will make the arguments `take` and `after` is the `DataFetchingEnvironment` in your `MyClassDataFetcher.get()` method, so you have an empty method that is not getting called but the arguments are still passed to your `DataFetcher`.

Again, it's not ideal because I doubt it's how it's meant to be used, but it's the only way of using a `DataFetcher` with arguments that I'm aware of.

Now, I didn't use any of those two solutions and I ended up dropping completely `graphql-annotations` and developed my own solution with custom annotations that are allowing me to automatically build the schema (won't be released publicly, sorry).

I wouldn't recommend using `graphql-annotations` until they have proper documentation for all the use cases.

Comment: As for today, the library is maintained again, and is documented. If you don't understand something, please open an issue and we will help you

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to look again at this library, as it is now back to be
maintained, and the readme is very clear.

As for you question:
You should make you field `listOfB` like this:

```
@GraphQLField
@GraphQLDataFetcher(ListOfBFetcher.class)
List<B> listOfB(int take){return null};
```

and in the dataFetcher you can get the `take` argument from the `environment` variable (via `enviroment.getArgument("take")`)

You can also make the method the dataFetcher itself by doing:

```
@GraphQLField
List<B> listOfB(int take, DataFetchingEnvironment environment){
    //return the list of B
  };
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the update. I don’t work on the project using GraphQL anymore though so it won’t be useful right now but if I ever get back to using GraphQL I’ll make sure to check the updates :)